# Approximating an Integral by Expanding it's Integrand

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, approximation

I am struggling with the following integral:
$$
\int_{\Gamma}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{1 + \frac{1}{z}}{e^{z} - 1} + \frac{1}{(e^{z} - 1)^{2}} \right] dz
$$
where $0 < \Gamma \ll 1$.

There is no closed form expression for this integral. I have however, noticed the following facts:
$$
\frac{1 + \frac{1}{z}}{e^{z} - 1} + \frac{1}{(e^{z} - 1)^{2}} \ = \ \frac{2}{z^{2}} - \frac{1}{2z} + \frac{z^{2}}{360} + \mathcal{O}(z^{4})
$$
$$
\lim_{z \to \infty} \left\{ \frac{1 + \frac{1}{z}}{e^{z} - 1} + \frac{1}{(e^{z} - 1)^{2}} \right\} = 0
$$

So to me at first glance, it would seem that my integral will vanish at the limit $z \to \infty$, and $maybe$ I can say that:
$$
\int_{\Gamma}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{1 + \frac{1}{z}}{e^{z} - 1} + \frac{1}{(e^{z} - 1)^{2}} \right] dz \approx \left[ 0 \right] - \left[ \int \left( \frac{2}{z^{2}} - \frac{1}{2z} \right) dz \right] \bigg|_{z = \Gamma} = \frac{1}{2}\log(\Gamma) + \frac{2}{\Gamma}
$$

I realize this is really informal and there is probably something wrong with this...but is there anything that can be said along these lines? I am really interested in a power series approximation of my integral!

Comment: The $z^k$ terms with $k \gt 0$ will blow up at $\infty$, so the expansion is invalid over the integration region.

Comment: This makes no sense. Your Laurent development is valid for small $z$ but you extend it to infinity and drop the positive powers !?

Comment: I believe the OP means to say that:
$$\int_\Gamma^\infty f(z)~dz=F(\infty)-F(\Gamma)$$
where $F(\Gamma)$ is approximated by the Laurent expansion and $F(\infty)=0$, though this is not true.  $F(\infty)$ is a non-zero constant when using the given expansion.  (Note that choosing a different $F$ will yield different constants of integration...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Lets $\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{z} \equiv
> {1 + 1/z \over \expo{z} - 1} + {1 \over \pars{\expo{z} - 1}^{2}}.\qquad
> 0 < \Gamma \ll 1}$.

\begin{align}
\int_{\Gamma}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{z}\,\dd z & =
\int_{\Gamma}^{1}\mrm{f}\pars{z}\,\dd z +
\int_{1}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{z}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
\braces{\int_{\Gamma}^{1}\pars{{2 \over z^{2}} - {1 \over 2z}}\,\dd z +
\int_{\Gamma}^{1}\bracks{\mrm{f}\pars{z} - {2 \over z^{2}} + {1 \over 2z}}
\,\dd z} +
\int_{1}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{z}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
-2 + {2 \over \Gamma} + {1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{\Gamma} -
\int_{0}^{\Gamma}\bracks{\mrm{f}\pars{z} - {2 \over z^{2}} + {1 \over 2z}}
\,\dd z\label{1}\tag{1}
\\ & +\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\mrm{f}\pars{z} - {2 \over z^{2}} +
{1 \over 2z}} + \int_{1}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{z}\,\dd z}
_{\ds{\equiv\ \alpha + 2}: \mbox{a constant}}
\end{align}

> The integral in \eqref{1} can be estimated by expanding
>   $\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{z} - {2 \over z^{2}} + {1 \over 2z}}$ in power of $\ds{z}$.

For instance,
$$
\int_{0}^{\Gamma}\bracks{\mrm{f}\pars{z} - {2 \over z^{2}} + {1 \over 2z}}
\,\dd z \sim
\int_{0}^{\Gamma}{z^{2} \over 360}\,\dd z = {\Gamma^{3} \over 1080}
\qquad\mbox{as}\quad \Gamma \to 0^{+}
$$
such that
$$
\bbx{\int_{\Gamma}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{z}\,\dd z \sim
{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{\Gamma} + {2 \over \Gamma} + \alpha + 
{\Gamma^{3} \over 1080}\qquad\mbox{as}\quad \Gamma \to 0^{+}}
$$

> Numerically, $\ds{\alpha \approx -1.1304}$.

Comment: I'd be inclined to reorder the terms: since $\Gamma \to 0^+$ the second and third terms are much bigger than the first and fourth terms.

Comment: It seems worth noting that the integration cutoff at $z=1$ is arbitrary; one could just as well do $z=2$, say, instead. (It's not obvious to me what the 'best' choice here is.)

Comment: @Ian Fixed. You're right. Thanks.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes. You're right. However, since $\Gamma \ll 1$ it seems 'natural' to me to choose the cutoff at $z = 1$. Any other one $> 0$ will work fine. Thanks.

Comment: Nice solution (as usual). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici